# face rig for my character model

Tags: mesh, rigging, rigify

Greeting everyone , I have a similar question I asked here with this topic but just different model and different idea
so here is my character model I created , first I want to animate the face rig , but this is a bear character kind of , so I want to rig the eyes the face the nose everything , does the face rig work? even though its a human rig not like an animal rig , and I could not find a good meta rig in the option , and My main question here is , I want to animate the blink eye , which is I never tried it before , there is a video I was watching : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1cY7Dr_ly4&ab_channel=MoazzamShah
my bear character his eyes are big outside his his face but that is what I wanted to be , its more like a cartoonish character or a pixar character etc , and every time I follow tutorial my body mesh is passing the eyes inside of it , there is no way I can make it outside , it just mess it up
is there  away to make it better? thanks in advance, I Will upload the blend file as if its hard to see the character in a picture
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be doable with your current topology, just make sure that the eye lid comes forwards enough so that it doesn't go behind the eye globe:

[image]

Topology of the second shapekey (use the *Proportional Editing* and enable its *Connected Only* option):

[image]

Comment: thank you for the help mate , appreciate it atleast worked but the bad news is , its my self i dont know why i have a hard time doing it , i tried the top eye top one and went to 3d cursor and tried it but didnt know exactly how to put it down , seems a bit hard or im not doing it properly , i am sorry im pretty bad with rigging as if i didnt try it much before , maybe like more detailed if u dont mind , thank you mate in anyway

Comment: Hello, a bit hard to explain in details but if you can join this Discord I can try: https://discord.gg/E6wXbR7A5S